# Android Picasso Authorization header not working

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp

I'am trying to addHeader to the Picasso request, so I've searched and followed what suggested to do, in this case adding an interceptor.But it's not working and not giving any error.

```
new Picasso.Builder(mContext).downloader(RestAsyncHttpClient.getOkHttpDownloader(header)).build()
            .load("https://myUrl.jpg").into(mMediaImageView);
```

And my okhttpDownload:

```
public static OkHttpDownloader getOkHttpDownloader(final HashMap<String, String> headers) {
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = mHttpClient.clone();

    okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();

            if (!headers.isEmpty())
                for (Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet())
                    builder.addHeader(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());

            Request newRequest = builder.build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
    });
    return new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient);
}
```

I've copied the header and the request and tried in postMan app and everything worked, I've also implemented OnImageLoadFailed but it's not triggered so i can't understand.

```
@Override
public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
    String test = "sad";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem wasn't Picasso or OkHhtp everything is at it should, but the problem was i made a mistake adding the header i was putting "MY TOKEN" "Authorization" instead of  "Authorization" "MY TOKEN. i will not delete the post because it contains a snippet of "how to add an header to Picasso"